Relative layout are going above the other layout
I want to have 2 lines: One with the content, the second with some buttons.
But, one line is not below the other, but is above the first one. Example here:

Here is my code:
private fun createLayout(width: Int = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, height: Int = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, align: Int = RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT): LayoutParams {
    val params = LayoutParams(width, height)
    params.addRule(align)
    return params
}

private fun createText(context: Context, text: String, layout: LayoutParams? = null): TextView {
    val view = TextView(context)
    view.text = text
    if(layout != null)
        view.layoutParams = layout
    return view
}

private fun createButton(context: Context, text: String, align: Int = RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT): Button {
    val btn = Button(context)
    btn.text = text
    btn.layoutParams = createLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, align)
    return btn
}

fun create(context: Context, card: Card, amount: Int): RelativeLayout {
    val cardLayout = RelativeLayout(context)
    val layout = RelativeLayout(context)
    val param = LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, getDpFromPixel(context, 40))
    param.setMargins(6,6,6,6)
    layout.layoutParams = param
    layout.setPadding(0, 12, 0, 6)
    layout.setBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.dark_gray))
    layout.addView(createText(context, "text 1"))
    val textId = createText(context, "text 2", createLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END))
    textId.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
    layout.addView(textId)
    cardLayout.addView(layout)
    val btnLayout = RelativeLayout(context)
    btnLayout.layoutParams = param
    btnLayout.addView(createButton(context, "+", RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START))
    btnLayout.addView(createText(context, amount.toString(), createLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)))
    btnLayout.addView(createButton(context, "-", RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END))
    cardLayout.addView(btnLayout)
    return cardLayout
}

How can I make the second line be BELOW the first one?
